# How to update json field in Firebase DB with JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm working with JMeter to make some HTTP Requests to my Firebase Database. I am able to create json data with a regular request, as well as with a CSV file. I'm wondering if it's possible to update, or add to, a json object.

My json data looks something like what is below. Let's say I wanted to add a boolean node called "sold", to which I could make equal to true or false. Could I create it within that json object? If so, could I also make it so that only fields with a specific "name" get updated?

```
{
"Price": "5.00",
"name": "buyer@gmail.com",
"seller_name": "seller@gmail.com",
"time": 1496893589683,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [Updating Data with PATCH](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update) chapter of [Saving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update) article you can update a single field using [HTTP PATCH Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH).

JMeter supports HTTP PATCH method since [version 2.8](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-28-hot-n-heavy) so you should be in a position to use it as well in your test.